# trying to get same results as regionsprops openCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

Here is the matlab code I'm trying to recode in openCV C++
Original
[image: Original]

Black and White
[image: Black And White]

Matlab result
[image: Matlab result]

OpenCV result
[image: OpenCV result]

OpenCV contours results which is similar to matlab contours result:
[image: OpenCV contours]

```
cDist=regionprops(bwImg, 'Area');
cDist=[cDist.Area];

% Label each object
[bwImgLabeled, ~]=bwlabel(bwImg);

% Calculate min and max object size based on assumptions on the color
% checker size
maxLabelSize = prod(size(imageData)./[4 6]);
minLabelSize = prod(size(imageData)./[4 6]./10);

% Find label indices for objects that are too large or too small
remInd = find(cDist > maxLabelSize);
remInd = [remInd find(cDist < minLabelSize)];
```

Here is my code:

```
bwImg.convertTo(bwImg,CV_8U);
cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours_1;
cv::findContours(bwImg,contours_1,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE,cv::Point(0,0));
//DEBUG contours
cv::Mat drawing1 = cv::Mat::zeros(bwImg.size(),CV_8UC3);    

for (int i = 0; i < contours_1.size(); i++)
{
    cv::RNG rng(12345);
    cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
    cv::drawContours(drawing1,contours_1,i,color,CV_FILLED);
}
//show contours update//
cv::imshow("contours",drawing1);        
cv::waitKey(0);

drawing1.release();
//% Calculate min and max object size based on assumptions on the color
//  % checker size
//  maxLabelSize = prod(size(imageData)./[4 6]);
//  minLabelSize = prod(size(imageData)./[4 6]./10);
double maxLabelSize = (bwImg.rows/4.0) * (bwImg.cols/6.0);
double minLabelSize = ((bwImg.rows/40.0) * (bwImg.cols/60.0));


//  % Remove over/undersized objects
//  for n=1:length(remInd)
//      ri = bwImgLabeled == remInd(n);
//      bwImgLabeled(ri) = 0;
//  end
cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > goodContours;
for (int i = 0; i < contours_1.size(); i++)
{
    double size = cv::contourArea(contours_1[i]);
    if (size < maxLabelSize && size > minLabelSize)
    {
        goodContours.push_back(contours_1[i]);
    }
}
```

however I do not get the same results. in matlab I get more contours then in openCV. can you see my problem?

Comment: Can you show how do the "contours" look like before the area filtering in opencv?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I added the pink image of  contours coming out of openCV

Comment: Comming out from Matlab or opencv? is that what `cv::imshow("contours",drawing1);` shows?

Comment: Have also a look at [connectedComponentsWithStats](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#connectedcomponents)

Comment: coming from OpenCV, this is the same result as matlab returns

Comment: @Gilad So basically what is happening is that the areas computed by Matlab and by openCV do not match? Try the following: Put an image with just a single "contour" or white blob, with a known area, and check what Matlab and opencv return on `size`.

Comment: @Miki i'm using 2.4.11 I think connectedComponents is from 3.0.0

Comment: Yep, from 3.0.0. I didn't see it mentioned in your question, though.